# Attacker knows what I do online and even has screenshots from my computer - how?

Tags: wireless, keyloggers, remote-desktop, spyware

What can be achieved by hacking the Wi-Fi connection? Can you then use that to access somebody else's computer remotely, i.e., from their own house instead of across the street from me?

I think someone is doing this to me. The person I'm suspecting gives me clues as to my online activity, in person. Also, the individual can take screenshots of my computer.

What can I do to protect myself? I run Windows 8, have 2 firewalls installed (plus Windows firewall). Will unplugging my Wi-Fi router help? Sorry if I'm not being too specific, but I don't know much about computers/security.

Comment: What makes you think someone compromised your network?

Comment: The person i'm suspecting gives me clues as to my online activity, in person.

Comment: I would suspect your machine to be compromised rather than your network. Nowadays most sites use HTTPS so someone only compromising your network won't be able to see much of what you do online, merely the sites you visit (without even knowing the exact pages).

Comment: so that's even worse.  anything I can do?

Comment: Well even with https, the attacker could see what Dave is doing online. For instance, watching Netflix all afternoon.

Comment: Dave, did you have any digital contact with that guy? Did you receive a funny email and open the attachment? Maybe he did not use his real name and you didn't know it was him.

Comment: Oh and if you don't rely on wifi, maybe turn the router off for the time being.

Comment: Hello potAito, I don't have any digital contact with him, no, and I don't think I clicked on anything malicious.  Whenever I open something, it's from trusted sources and my system scans it.  So, no.  Wifi is turned off right now, but, I think he has even better access to my computer, and doesn't need the wifi.

Answer (score 2):

**If all this is overwhelming to you, get a friend to help you or hire someone. Also, consider filing a lawsuit if you strongly believe this person is spying on you. This is illegal!**

### What can you do

Most likely the attacker got into your wireless network because you are using an old router with weak encryption or your chosen password is weak. He could have compromised devices inside your network afterwards, but that requires a more sophisticated attacker, making this scenario less likely. But not impossible! So here are the actions I would take:

1. If he nested on one of your devices, it could be close to impossible to find out how he did it. Easiest choice might be to reinstall your operating system from scratch. Also, if you have more devices in your network than just your computer, you might have to reset these to factory settings as well. But to be honest I'm unexperienced how to deal with a compromised smart tv or similar.
2. **Note: This step is useless if your system is compromised. He can log your keystrokes and will know the new password!** You should change the wireless password. If you don't know how, search online for the manual of your model. If you can't login, there's always a way to reset the device to factory settings, often by holding the reset button for a specified number of seconds. But be aware, that you'll then have to reconfigure the router yourself before you can use it again. You won't have wireless unless you finish the configuration.
3. **Note: This step is useless if your system is compromised. He can log your keystrokes and will know the new passwords!** You should change your online login credentials (hotmail, facebook, google, netflix etc.). Specifically those for the sites that this person is referring to in your conversations. This might be a great time to start using a password manager like [keepass](http://keepass.info/). There are also plenty of online password managers if you fear to accidentally loser your password database.

### Help us help you

We could help you a lot better if you could explain **why** you believe that someone is inside your network. So here are a bunch of starting points for you:
 - What happened? When did it happen? What exactly did you observe?
 - What Wireless router are you using?
 - What wireless encryption are you using? You can find out by logging into the web interface of your router in case you did not know. 
 - What devices are connected to your network? Television, smart phone, tablet, home server, raspberry pi, notebook computer etc...

### Regarding mutiple firewalls

Running multiple software firewalls will not improve your security. You mean it well, but it could worsen your overall security. Typically when you install a software firewall, it will deactivate your windows firewall automatically. Decide for yourself which one you want to use. The Windows firewall is a legitimate choice.

### Possible Attacks

Next I'll address your question what someone can do once he enters your network. This is most likely not a complete list:

1. The first thing to realize is, that this person now has the key to your wireless network. An eavesdropper can then read all your web traffic. Luckily HTTPS adds another layer of security such that your login credentials are encrypted between your computer and the server. There are however still websites out there which handle the implementation poorly or do not use HTTPS at all for the login form. In that case your unwelcome guest could obtain your login credentials. Even worse, if you are using the same credentials on other sites, he now has access to these as well if he finds out about them. This by the way is one of the reasons why you should use a different password for every website and maintain them with a password manager.
2. Your devices are no longer protected by your router with [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). If you are running local network services or have a NAS, Smart TV etc. in your private network, the attacker could now communicate directly with them. He or she could find security exploits and compromise your devices. From there on, depending on your setup, everything is possible.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do any of that, change my credentials and key.  I tried logging into my router webpage, but the l/p on the back does not work, so I can't modify anything.  Is that where I should log in?  Like I said, I don't know about these things.  I tried finding out about the type of encryption my router is using, but I couldn't.  My wifi router is Linksys.  Also, is it necessary for a hacker to be close to my house, in a van or something, or can he now gain access from his own computer, far away from me?

Comment: (cont)  That is, after he hacks my Wifi.  Like I said, my experience with computer security is what I've been reading online for the past 2 days!  Ok about firewalls, i'm using both TinyWall and Comodo.  WindowsFirewall still claims it is on.  When you say "credentials" you mean like Hotmail l/p and things?

Comment: Don't worry Dave, you are doing fine. He could have been in vicinity when he hacked your wifi the first time and then it's possible that he nested somehow. He could very well have an entry point now without having to be near your home.

Comment: Yes by credentials I meant logins to facebook, hotmail etc. But first we need to figure out how he nows about your activities. Otherwise a password change might be completely useless.

Comment: Yes, I kinda gathered that.  If the system is compromised, he can just find out the new l/p.  Thanks for replying btw, I didn't even realize you're the original replier.

Comment: Ok guys so any more suggestions?  Things I could do?  Any idea what is happening to my computer?  I don't know how to change my wireless key.  I tried logging in using the l/p on the back of my wireless router, but it won't let me in.  Also, will changing this "key" prevent the hacker from having access to me?  Won't he just "find it" again?  This is all very, very confusing to me.  Please help.

Comment: @Dave I updated my answer with some more instructions. By the way, on this site it's easiest to edit questions and answers with more information rather than adding it through comments. I've done that for you with your question if you take a close look :) But feel free to add anything else that you think could help. The more information, the better.

Comment: Yes, you literally hacked my initial question :).  The individual can take screen shots of my screen.  I don't think changing the password would do anything, because he knows what i say on chat sites, so that is not logged,like say on FaceBook/email  So you're saying, If I understand correctly, there's a chance that his hacking and spying on me is STILL being done wirelessly, and not from his house..etc.?  I should point out that he knows how to program, in several languages.  He of course denies he's very skilled in computers in general, from what I read a typical hacker tactic.

Comment: @Dave This means he definitely compromised your system, so changing passwords will do nothing as long as he can "watch" you do it. You could try a bootable anti-virus CD (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/system-security/tp/free-bootable-antivirus-software.htm) to find the malware. But chances are you won't if he really is that good and targeted you specifically. I suggest you reinstall your operating system and THEN go about changing all your passwords.

Comment: Yes, my system looks too legit to quit :).  Shouldn't there be a more pronounced upload bandwidth consumption?  How is he getting all this done while being so stealthy?

Comment: @Dave A screen cap can be compressed to a few kilobytes. No chance to detect that unless you know what you are looking for.

Comment: I see a message I should move this to chat, but I don't have enough privileges.  My wireless router is Lynksys EA6100 model.  I looked for a manual, and all I could find is that you can only change the password through an online settings thing.  Also, do I have to change the password for both my Ethernet modem and Wireless router as well?  Is the "default gateway" in ipconfig my Ethernet modem's address or Wireless router address?  Also should I start a new message to ask these questions.  Thanks.  Maybe you can move it for me.

Comment: @Dave Sure, you can always open new questions. Just be sure to select the proper sub community on stackexchange. I can't move anything, I'm just a peasant here :). And please consider contacting the police!! I would.

Comment: I don't know about contacting the police.  There's no visible signs of an entry on my machine, etc.  Do they have experience with these kinds of situations, that you know of?  Plus it would probably involve them installing software on my machine and a whole new mess.  Plus, what proof can I present to the cops that is not "speculation"?  What proof will they have to charge the intruder/obtain a search warrant?  Wouldn't someone of his competence not hack from home or take the precautionary measures to not be caught?  I think so.  But please tell me if i'm wrong, which is quite possible.

Comment: Potaito, can I contact you personally?

Comment: @Dave Sorry for the late reply. Hm I don't know how since stackexchange sites have no concept of private messages and I would rather not post my personal information here. Maybe you can open another question?

Comment: Ok.  I understand.

Answer (score 0):

When your WiFi network is breached you have to assume that **any device** on your network is compromised.

The best way to stay safe is to have a strong WiFi password and strong password on all your devices as well as updates versions and be aware of any weird activity.